# Sending notifications from Firebase cloud messaging to a single device

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are building an app with chat functionality in Flutter, and I have figured out almost everything about how it should be done, except how the notifications can be sent to only one device (Or possibly a few devices).

The best option so far is to send the notification to an FCM registration token since we use Firebase for all of our back-end, but I can't do that without knowing the token. And the only way I can know that is to store it in Firestore (For example the users document) and retrieve it when needed. Is this a good solution, and what happens if the registration token changes? Should I update the token every time the user opens the app to make sure that it is correct?

Comment: Storing the token in a database is quite common. To store the token you typically only need to listen to the [`onTokenRefresh` stream](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_messaging/latest/firebase_messaging/FirebaseMessaging/onTokenRefresh.html). On Android you'd do that in a background handler, so that the code also is active when the app is not being used. But I'm not sure how to accomplish the same on Flutter. If that isn't possible, doing this each time when the app starts is indeed a valid solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I can execute code in the background, I will look into it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to store the token on the server, you just need to know who you are sending the message to. Just follow these steps

Client

1.a When you app starts, retrieve the token via `getToken()`

1.b Store it locally

1.c if it has changed, send it to a Cloud function, and register it to a [topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/topic-messaging) or [device group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/device-group)

1.d Dont forget to register to `onTokenRefresh()` to repeat 1.a-c for new tokens

Server

2.a Implement the function corresponding to 1.c

2.b When required, send messages to a topic or device group

Comment: I can subscribe to topics directly from flutter, I assume that is the same thing as 1.c? Also, it is not recommended to use topics to send notifications to single devices according to here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging

But maybe that is the best solution anyway?

Comment: You can choose topic or device group, as you wish

Comment: Can you subscribe to topics directly from the client? I though it was an action that required higher privileges and could only be done from the server...

Comment: FirebaseMessaging().subscribeToTopic('topic') in flutter at least

Comment: Dont you have to provide the FCM Server Key?

Comment: I believe that's included in the config files that you download when configuring the app on the Firebase console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217275/discussion-between-oliver-and-hannes-hultergard).

Comment: It may sound like common knowledge, but I have been having a very hard time finding out how to create a notificationkey and notificationkeyname for a device group. Some of the websites I've visited says nothing about how to actually code the notificationKey corresponding to tokens. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Running around, all I could see is this for subscribing to a topic that is the userId. http://blog.wafrat.com/notifications-in-flutter/